# Js linq: group by 2 properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, jslinq

I've the following array:

```
    var data = [
  {street: "Галенка", house: "11", flats: "10,11,12,13,17,18,21,24,27,29,3,30,32,33,36,4,40", isNotApply: false},
  {street: "Галенка", house: "3", flats: "1,12,14,15,16,19,2,21,23,24,28,29,3,30,31,32,6", isNotApply: true},
  {street: "Літке", house: "110", flats: "0", isNotApply: true},
  {street: "Вадима Гурова", house: "11", flats: "10,100,101,102,104,105", isNotApply: false},
  {street: "Вадима Гурова", house: "120", flats: "0", isNotApply: true}
];
```

I got this result using GroupBy and this nice, but how can I set *IsNotApply* as key to this 2 arrays?

```js
var data = [
  {street: "Галенка", house: "11", flats: "10,11,12,13,17,18,21,24,27,29,3,30,32,33,36,4,40,4…6,58,61,64,65,67,68,69,7,70,71,73,75,76,78,8,80,9", isNotApply: false},
  {street: "Галенка", house: "3", flats: "1,12,14,15,16,19,2,21,23,24,28,29,3,30,31,32,6", isNotApply: true},
  {street: "Літке", house: "110", flats: "0", isNotApply: true},
  {street: "Вадима Гурова", house: "11", flats: "10,100,101,102,104,105,106,107,109,110,111,112,113…73,75,76,79,8,81,82,83,85,86,88,90,91,94,95,96,99", isNotApply: false},
  {street: "Вадима Гурова", house: "120", flats: "0", isNotApply: true}
];

result = Enumerable.From(data)
        .GroupBy(
            "{IsNotApply: $.isNotApply, House: $.house}",
            "{Street: $.street, House: $.house, Flats: $.flats}",
            "{ data: $$.ToArray(), isNotApply: $.IsNotApply }",
            "$.IsNotApply"
        )
        .ToArray();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.js"></script>
```

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: Like this `false: {data: Array(2)}
true: {data: Array(3)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a function for getting the wanted key for the part result object.

```js
var data = [{ street: "Галенка", house: "11", flats: "10,11,12,13,17,18,21,24,27,29,3,30,32,33,36,4,40,4…6,58,61,64,65,67,68,69,7,70,71,73,75,76,78,8,80,9", isNotApply: false }, { street: "Галенка", house: "3", flats: "1,12,14,15,16,19,2,21,23,24,28,29,3,30,31,32,6", isNotApply: true }, { street: "Літке", house: "110", flats: "0", isNotApply: true }, { street: "Вадима Гурова", house: "11", flats: "10,100,101,102,104,105,106,107,109,110,111,112,113…73,75,76,79,8,81,82,83,85,86,88,90,91,94,95,96,99", isNotApply: false }, { street: "Вадима Гурова", house: "120", flats: "0", isNotApply: true }],
    result = Enumerable
        .From(data)
        .GroupBy(
            "$.isNotApply",
            "{ Street: $.street, House: $.house, Flats: $.flats }",
            "(k, v) => ({ [k]: v.ToArray() })"
        )
        .ToArray();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added the snippets for both **JS** and **Linq**.

```js
var data = [
  {street: "Галенка", house: "11", flats: "10,11,12,13,17,18,21,24,27,29,3,30,32,33,36,4,40,4…6,58,61,64,65,67,68,69,7,70,71,73,75,76,78,8,80,9", isNotApply: false},
  {street: "Галенка", house: "3", flats: "1,12,14,15,16,19,2,21,23,24,28,29,3,30,31,32,6", isNotApply: true},
  {street: "Літке", house: "110", flats: "0", isNotApply: true},
  {street: "Вадима Гурова", house: "11", flats: "10,100,101,102,104,105,106,107,109,110,111,112,113…73,75,76,79,8,81,82,83,85,86,88,90,91,94,95,96,99", isNotApply: false},
  {street: "Вадима Гурова", house: "120", flats: "0", isNotApply: true}
];

console.log(data);

//Javascript
var result = {};        
data.forEach(function(item){
    item = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item));
    var bool = item.isNotApply;
    delete item.isNotApply;
    result[bool] = result[bool] || {data:[],isNotApply:bool};
    result[bool].data.push(item);
})

console.log("Javascript result : ",result);

//Linq
result = Enumerable.From(data)
        .GroupBy(
            "{IsNotApply: $.isNotApply, House: $.house}",
            "{Street: $.street, House: $.house, Flats: $.flats}",
            "{ data: $$.ToArray(), isNotApply: $.IsNotApply }",
            "$.IsNotApply"
        )
        .ToObject("$.isNotApply");
        
console.log("Linq JS result : ",result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.js"></script>
```